# how to open a connection to an existing .sql file not using sql toolbox?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I would like to try to use visual studio as an SQL(lite3) editor. I discovered the SQL server compact & SQLite Toolbox, but have a problem finding an easy enough tutorial. I would like to connect to an already existing .sql file any suggestions on how to make this as easy as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot coonect to a .sql file, this is a text file with sql commands. But use the root menu in the toolbox to connect to an existing or new sqlite database.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to Your guidance I am using your toolbox. It Works really nicely except that whenever I (in the SQL server compact/SQLite Toolbox) want to see the tables within the Tables-folder (data Connections->"my database file" -> Tables ->) it crashes and forces a restart of Visual studio..

Comment: Please file a bug report here: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create and attache the database causing the crash and I will fix this issue.